# How can I render the Flutter UI for these posts?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a Flutter app that fetches and posts from an API. Here is the code. I can't seem to make the code render the posts on the UI, it comes back as black with a single white box.

I have been debugging, the posts and fetches work fine and the console logs the JSON being retrieved but somehow it can't render on the UI.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:dawgs/Discussion.dart';
import 'package:dawgs/components/WallPost.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dawgs/components/text_field.dart';
import 'dart:developer' as developer;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'The Buzz',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme:
            ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 32, 7, 80)),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final titleController = TextEditingController();
  final messageController = TextEditingController();
  late Future<List<Discussion>> _future_list_discussions;
  final backendUrl = "https://team-dawgs.dokku.cse.lehigh.edu";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _future_list_discussions = fetchDiscussions();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return build_v3(context);
  }

   Widget build_v3(BuildContext context) {
    var fb = FutureBuilder<List<Discussion>>(
      future: _future_list_discussions,
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Discussion>> snapshot) {
        Widget child;

        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          // developer.log('`using` ${snapshot.data}', name: 'my.app.category');
          // create  listview to show one row per array element of json response
          child = ListView.builder(
              //shrinkWrap: true, //expensive! consider refactoring. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
              itemBuilder: /*1*/ (context, i) {
                return Card(
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 32.0, bottom: 32.0, left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            snapshot.data![i].title,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            snapshot.data![i].message,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )),
                );
              });
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          // newly added
          child = Text('${snapshot.error}');
        } else {
          // awaiting snapshot data, return simple text widget
          // child = Text('Calculating answer...');
          child = const CircularProgressIndicator(); //show a loading spinner.
        }
        return child;
      },
    );

    return fb;
  }
}

/* // Post Discussion
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: MyTextField(
                      controller: titleController,
                      hintText: 'Title now!',
                      obscureText: false,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  Expanded(
                    child: MyTextField(
                      controller: messageController,
                      hintText: 'Content please',
                      obscureText: false,
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _future_list_discussions = postDiscussion(
                          titleController.text,
                          messageController.text,
                        );
                      });
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_up),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  } */

Future<List<Discussion>> postDiscussion(String title, String message) async {
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://team-dawgs.dokku.cse.lehigh.edu/discussions'),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
      'mTitle': title,
      'mMessage': message,
    }),
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final responseBody = jsonDecode(response.body);

    // Check if the response body is in the expected format
    if (responseBody is List<dynamic>) {
      // Map each item in the list to a Discussion object
      return responseBody.map((item) => Discussion.fromJson(item)).toList();
    }
  }

  // Throw a generic error if any unexpected scenario occurs
  throw Exception(
      'Failed to post a discussion. Status code: ${response.statusCode}, Reason: ${response.reasonPhrase}');
}

Future<List<Discussion>> fetchDiscussions() async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('https://team-dawgs.dokku.cse.lehigh.edu/discussions'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response, then parse the JSON.
    final List<Discussion> returnData;
    var res = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print('json decode: $res');

    if (res is List) {
      returnData =
          (res as List<dynamic>).map((x) => Discussion.fromJson(x)).toList();
    } else if (res is Map) {
      returnData = <Discussion>[
        Discussion.fromJson(res as Map<String, dynamic>)
      ];
    } else {
      developer
          .log('ERROR: Unexpected json response type (was not a List or Map).');
      returnData = List.empty();
    }
    return returnData;
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Did not receive success status code from request.');
  }
}
```

I tried different ways and different YouTube videos to render it differently but nothing worked. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed adding the scaffold

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: build_v3(context),
    );
  }
```